# How to print JSON data in a loop in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this JSON Data

```
{
"districtData": {
    "East Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "South West Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "West Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "South Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "North East Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "North Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "North West Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    },
    "Unknown": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I want to print it in a loop and want to display like

```
East Delhi    lastupdatedtime 
North west   lastupdatedtime
```

and so on

```html
<tr v-for="data in jsonData" :key="data.id"> 
   <td>{{ data}}</td>
</tr>
```

I tried but I am getting only `lastupdatedtime`.  Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `jsonData` here? also the "JSON Data" you have shared has no `id` property then how are you assigning `:key="data.id"`?

Comment: i am fetching data using api call and storing it into jsonData object and :key="data.id" is necessary in vuejs otherwise it will not allow and through error

Comment: @LR yes but it  must have id in the obj as well for this to work

Comment: But where is the `id` in  jsonData object??

Comment: ohh sorry but what to do ? any suggestion

Comment: Nothing can't be done as we don't know what does `jsonData` looks like? `console.log( jsonData )` and post the image in the post for review.

Comment: jsonData is exactly same as  i have mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two imporatnt fixes required in this code:

1. Since there is no `id` in data you should use city name instead as it is unique
2. Also, you should use the `(value, key) in object` approach for your problem.

An example of this code can be:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(cityData, city) in districtData" :key="city">
      {{city}} - {{cityData.lastupdatedtime}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

you can also use this pen for testing: https://codepen.io/abdullah-shabaz/pen/MWwZQYo

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
 <tr v-for="(data,index) in jsonData" :key="index"> 
  <td>{{ data.districtData}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: thanks @ziakhan but it is displaying whole data as it is

Comment: if still you didnt understand then send me your proper array i will interpret for you, the way you want

Comment: Thanks you below code work for me thankyo for your time

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for this to work you must have a proper formatted object.

```
{
"districtData": {
    "East Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "id": 1
    },
    "South West Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "id": 2
    },
    "West Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
         "id": 3
    },
    "Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": "" 
        "id": 4
    },
    "South Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": "" 
         "id": 5
    },
    "North East Delhi": {
        "lastupdatedtime": ""
       "id": 7
    }
}
```

and you key districtData will be use to loop through

Comment: thansk @Mr Khan, but  i am fetching data from third party api i can't add id in that

Comment: you can still  append this id to the response object.

Comment: how to append id any suggesstion?

Comment: Thankyou for your time i got output

Answer (score 0):

If the jsonData is like this.

```
jsonData = {
    "districtData": {
        "East Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "South West Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "West Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "South Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "North East Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "North Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "North West Delhi": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        },
        "Unknown": {
            "lastupdatedtime": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Please try below 2 methods.

It is to show all items in the object

```
<tr v-for="(data, index) in jsonData.districtData" :key="data.id"> 
    <td> {{ index }} </td>
    <template v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
        <td> {{item}} </td>
    </template>
</tr>
```

It is to show lastupdatedtime.

```
<tr v-for="(data, index) in jsonData.districtData" :key="data.id"> 
    <td> {{ index }} </td>
    <td> {{data.lastupdatedtime}} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: index is showing "districtData" and  data is showing whole data as it is